# How to read a file and make a new one while editing the output?

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm trying to do this:

Option 3: Download Statistics

If the user chooses this option, the program will create a statistics file with the following data:

a. Power output sorted from lowest to highest
b. Day with highest output
c. Total by month
d. Average power output for all the data

The statistics file will have the same name as the input file but with _stats.txt appended to it. For example, if the input file was named data.txt, the stats file will be named data_stats.txt.

Note: It will remove the .txt from data.txt, before adding the _stats.txt. It will NOT create a file with the name data.txt_stats.txt. You can use the String.subString() method to remove the last 4 characters from the file name.

Write a method called CreateStatsFile to do this task. Choose the appropriate parameters and return type.

Once done creating the statistics file, the main menu will be displayed again.

How would I do A-D? I have my loop set up properly I think.

This is what is in the data.txt file

```
January 10 2018 236.9
January 11 2018 267.6
January 12 2018 278.1
January 13 2018 246.9
January 14 2018 262.3
January 15 2018 288.6
February 2 2018 199.7
February 3 2018 134.6
February 4 2018 200.8
February 5 2018 198.2
March 9 2018 169.7
March 10 2018 168.3
March 11 2018 179.4
```

I think I have my loop set up properly

```
 public static String createStatsFile () throws IOException
{
   File file = new File("data.txt");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
   while(sc.hasNext())
   {
       System.out.println(sc.);
   }
```

Comment: Well, you'd need to parse those lines, e.g. parse the month, day and year into a `Date` and the last number (power output?) into a `Double` or `BigDecimal`. Then build a list of objects that contain those 2 data points, e.g. a `List<StatisticsEntry>`. Once you have that in place you could try to implement A-D. - Note that this feels like a lesson meant to teach _you_ a thing or two so _you_ need to implement it and do some research.

Comment: oh man, I have no idea how to do that ugh, what do you mean by parse?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-parsing-mean-in-Java - you basically convert a string (lines in your case) into more useable data (a date and a number in your case).

Comment: Okay, did I do this properly?   File file = new File("data.txt");
     Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
     while(input.hasNext()) {
         String date = input.next();
         double powerOutput = input.nextDouble();

Comment: No `String date = input.next();` would return one string but you actually have 3 for the date. You could do 3 calls to `input.next()` to get the month, day and year. Rereading your requirements you'd probably not need to actually parse them. It would be sufficient to store those 3 values in the resulting object and only use the `month` field ffor the aggregate required in C.

Comment: okay, how would I call it three times? I tried just copying two more times but it's not working, Would this work?  String month = input.next();
         String day = input.next();
         String year = input.next();

Comment: That looks about right. However note that you'd need to also need to continue reading until you're out of input. Since `Scanner.next()` can be tricky at times I'd suggest reading the lines first by using `Scanner.nextLine()` and then splitting the line into an array using `String.split("\\s+")` on the line (`\s+` is a regular expression matching whitespace of at least length 1). You'd then get a `String[]` and could work your way from there (e.g. via `Double.parseDouble(array[3])`).

Comment: I tried doing  monthArray=month.split("a"); is this kinda what you mean? I'm getting an error under monthArray but should I be creating 3 of these splits or just one for all three Strings?

Comment: No, you read the _entire_ line and then do something like `String[] parts = line.split("\\s+"); String month = parts[0]; ...`

Answer (score 0):

Such data structure conversion tasks have ideally 3 steps:

1. You read the the input and convert it into an internal data structure.
2. You make some additional tranformations on the data structure, if needed.
3. You print this data structure.

As the comments say, typically (1) has the most troubles, and it is called *parsing*.

However, typically doing these steps clearly separated in your source code spares a lot of trouble.

The important thing is this: *load an interpret your input file only once.* After that you have it in your program memory, probably as some set of records, you can do with easily as you want.

There is no need to parse this file multiple times.

Your input data structure should follow the structure of your input. The main task of (2) is the conversion of your data structure which is more easily processable for (3).

(2) would mean in your case mainly to extend your data structure with aggregated results (average values, sum or so on).